# Oracle. apply Conditional ordering. If >=2 rows have duplicate data, those rows must follow a seperate condition to those that don't have duplicates

Tags: sql, oracle

```
Select custno, custname, location
From customer
Order by
```

The order of the results have to fit the following criteria:

custno, custnames and location in ascending location sequence. **If 2 or more rows have the same location, list only those rows in ascending custname sequence.**

I don't even know where to begin with the 2nd part of the question.
I found questions somewhat similar to this and it was advised to use case with when, but I've never used that before, and not sure what to begin. Here's where I'm at so far

```
Select custno, custname, location
From customer
Order by
Case 
    when count(location) >= 2
    then custname asc
    else location asc
    end
```

[This is the pic of the results they provided.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KrSBq.jpg)

And the statements that was provided.

```
create table GRADE (
gradeID varchar2(2),
description varchar2(20),
Primary Key (gradeID) );
create table TYPE (
TypeCode number,
Title varchar2(20),
gradeID varchar2(2),
category varchar2(1),
Primary Key (TypeCode),
Foreign Key (gradeID) references GRADE );
create table customer(
custno number,
custname varchar2(20),
typecode number,
sales number(7,2),
location varchar2(20),
Primary Key (custno),
Foreign Key (typecode) references TYPE );

Insert into grade (gradeID,description) values ('WC','Women and
Children');
Insert into grade (gradeID,description) values ('M','Men');
Insert into TYPE (TypeCode,Title,gradeID,category) values (1,'Under
20','WC','X');
Insert into TYPE (TypeCode,Title,gradeID,category) values (2,'Under
20','M','Z');
Insert into TYPE (TypeCode,Title,gradeID,category) values (3,'20
plus','WC','Z');
Insert into TYPE (TypeCode,Title,gradeID,category) values (4,'20
plus','M','X');
Insert into TYPE (TypeCode,Title,gradeID,category) values
(5,'Special','M','S');
Insert into customer (custno, custname, TypeCode,sales,location) values
(21,'Wendy',1,300,'Haw');
Insert into customer (custno, custname, TypeCode,sales,location) values
(24,'Sue',3,700,'Haw');
Insert into customer (custno, custname, TypeCode,sales,location) values
(27,'Nick',2,NULL,'Kew');
Insert into customer (custno, custname, TypeCode,sales,location) values
(22,'Dave',4,95,'Richmond');
Insert into customer (custno, custname, TypeCode,sales,location) values
(25,'Jenny',1,525,'Haw');
Insert into customer (custno, custname, TypeCode,sales,location) values
(29,'Bob',4,15,'Kew');
Insert into customer (custno, custname, TypeCode,sales,location) values
(23,'Helen',3,200,'Haw');
Insert into customer (custno, custname, TypeCode,sales,location) values
(28,'Linda',1,25,'Kew');
Insert into customer (custno, custname, TypeCode,sales,location) values
(26,'Xena',3,Null, 'Richmond');
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

Start with a query that returns nr of identical rows, then select only rows with nr > 1:

```
select ...
  from customer c,
       (
         Select count(*) nr, location
         From customer
         Group by location
       ) n
where n.nr > 1
  and c.l = n.l
```

This isn't a complete query, but you get the idea. It is hard for me to get this exactly right without having your table.